# regex not stop when using dot matches

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, pattern-matching

I want to remove some scripts from pages that contain the word "site"

```
<scritp>
o.com
bla bla bla
</script><p>this is line></p>

<script>
google.com/jquery.js !
</script>

<scritp>
site.com
bla bla bla
</script><p>aa</p>

CONTENT
STYLE
SIDEBAR
...


<scritp>
site.com
aaa bla bla bla
</script><p>a</p>
```

I am using the following regular expression:

```
<scritp>.*?site.*?<\/script>
```

But it contains lines that are not related to the matches.

debug link : https://regex101.com/r/rC0vF8/2

How can I stop when I find a match for: `</script>`

I want to match all `<script>site.com</script>` at once

Comment: [`<scritp>[^<s]*(?:<(?!\/?scri(?:tp|pt)\b)[^<s]*|s(?!ite\.)[^<s]*)*site\.[^<]*(?:<(?!\/?scri(?:tp|pt)\b)[^<]*)*<\/script>`](https://regex101.com/r/xR6aG5/3)

Comment: Same as @Felippe Duarte, it only works if the first word after the opening <script> tag is site, not it "site" is included anywhere inside the tag. Though maybe that's what user3325376 wants

Comment: No, [it works](https://regex101.com/r/xR6aG5/4).

Comment: My bad, first time didn't work ... sorry :)

Comment: I'd just use a neg. lookahead: [`<script>((?!</script).)*?site(?1)*</script>`](https://regex101.com/r/oX5kS1/1) if this would be sufficient for your input. Also be aware that in your sample/demo you write some `scritp` and some `script` is this meant?

Comment: @bobblebubble You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - excellent regex!  +1 (But note that a non-ASCII Unicode colon ":" slipped into the second `(?:<` part of your comment.)

Comment: @ridgerunner There was no nonASCII in what I typed. It is an SO bug in rendering comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusing looks, that you have some `scritp` and some `script` in your sample & demo. Is this meant? However you can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if this would be convenient for your input:

```
<script>((?!</script).)*?site(?1)*</script>
```

- `((?!</script).)*?` matches [lazily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) any amount of any characters while `</script` not ahead
- until `site` and `(?1)*` [reuses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) the pattern in first [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) until `</script>` greedily.

More explanation and [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oX5kS1/1)

For this kind of problems usually a [parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) solution is be to be preferred. Depends on input.

Comment: your code perfectly worked in regex101.com , but unfortunately it's not working in php , it's make page never-end loading , you can test it in code generator [link](http://regex101.com/r/eN8oW9/1)

Comment: @user3325376 Hmm, it works for me. Try [`$str = preg_replace('~<script>((?!</script).)*?criteo(?1)*</script>~si', "__REMOVED__", $str);`](https://eval.in/581644). Maybe you had `/` as pattern delimiter or some limits set too low in php.ini

Comment: This regex is more readable, but less efficient than what I suggested in the comment. A tempered greedy token should be greedy, shouldn't it? :-) Anyway, I suggest unrolling these constructs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why not just unroll your answer? Imho throwing in a huge regex comment without any explanation does not really help. I put the answer because I thought it's compromise between performance and readability / not so hard to understand. I know that your regex is of better performance. If you think you learnt some nice terminology from rexegg or elsewhere for a common practice that's good for you (: I just wrote that from feeling. If it's wrong or can be improved let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex instead: `/<scritp>\nsite.*?<\/script>/gsi`

Your regex will fetch the first `<script>` then next `site.*` then last `</script>`

Comment: This works only if the first word after the opening `<script>` tag is site, otherwise it doesn't.